# Estoy intentando emular un botón de 2 estados en un google spreadsheet con apps scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Quiero emular un botón de 2 estados ("Carregar Seu" y "Recarregar Seu"). Cada estado se corresponde con una imagen, y asociada a esta, tiene asignada una función que se ejecuta al pinchar en la imagen.
Este es el resumen de mi codigo:

```
function recarregar(){
  const boto=trauImatges("0.Paràmetres","recarregar");
  var novaImatgeBlob = DriveApp.getFolderById("1go_9szYgFu0c8KkqGUAfQfNgx3ICtQ5E").getFilesByName("Carrega.png").next().getBlob();
  boto.replace(novaImatgeBlob.copyBlob()).assignScript("carregar"); 
  // lA.getSheetByName("joanc").activate();
  boto.assignScript("carregar");
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  //fA.activate();
}
function carregar(){
  const boto=trauImatges("0.Paràmetres","carregar");
  var novaImatgeBlob = DriveApp.getFolderById("1go_9szYgFu0c8KkqGUAfQfNgx3ICtQ5E").getFilesByName("Recarrega.png").next().getBlob();
  //boto.assignScript("recarregar");
  boto.replace(novaImatgeBlob.copyBlob()); 
  //lA.getSheetByName("joanc").activate();  
  boto.assignScript("recarregar");
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  //fA.activate();
  
}
function trauImatges(full,boto){
  const imatges = fA.getImages();
  for(let i=0;i<imatges.length;i++){
     if(imatges[i].getScript()==boto){ 
        return imatges[i];   }
        
  };
}
```

En este resumen, la acción de cada botón es la de cambiar una imagen por la otra, y asignar la funcion correspondiente.
Funcionar, funciona, pero no de forma satisfactoria.

-Si cambio la imagen sin asignar la función, el cambio de imagen se realiza de forma satisfactoria, pero necesito asignar la función al nuevo estado del botón.

-Si asigno la función tal y como está en el código que os he puesto, el cambio se realiza, pero la nueva imagen no aparece en la sheet. Apesar del `SpreadsheetApp.flush();` el objeto imagen esta en la sheet pero no se muestra. Para conseguir que se muestre tengo que recargar la sheet o como muestra el codigo conmentado, cambiar a otra hoja `lA.getSheetByName("joanc").activate();` y volver a la misma `fA.activate();`
Esto último es la solución menos mala que he encontrado, pero no me acaba de convencer.
¿Alguien puede ayudarme con una solución mejor? Gracias por vuestra atención.

Answer (score 0):

Despues de perlearme mucho con este tema os pongo aqui la solucion que he encontrado.
La solucion necesita que creemos un indice que nos diga la posición de cada imagen en el array de imagenes de la hoja.

Tenemos que cargar previamente las imagenes anclandolas a una celda que no se muestra, con `.insertImage(url, column, row, offsetX, offsetY)` y anotamos su indice .
Con sheet.getImages()[indice].setHeight() o setWidth() le damos las dimesiones y la dejamos preparada para cuando la necesitemos.

Como se trata de simular un boton de 2 o más estados, cuando queramos cambiar una imagen por otra, simplemente hacemos  `sheet.getImages()[indice].setAnchor(range)`  para desplazar la imagen actual a una celda donde no se muestre, y lo mismo para llevar la nueva imagen a la celda donde queremos mostrarla.

Esta es una solucion que a mi me ha servido. Estoy abierto a soluciones más optimas.